# Libre Calc -- How to link to cells in another workbook

Tags: libreoffice

To link cells between worksheets, I simply click the "=" sign, go to the appropriate cell in another worksheet, and hit "enter." Each time I update one or more source worksheets, the target worksheet cell updates. Works like a charm.

However, this doesn't work between workBOOKs. The link to the source file gets duplicated and invalidated each time I open the target workbook. This technique works fine between files in Excel, but is there a way to do it in Libre?

Comment: The irony of this question is that I must admit that if I knew the answer, I'd probably offer it, but then I'd probably also mention that even though LibreOffice comes with Ubuntu by default, this question is actually just as off topic as any question about the Rhythmbox music player which is also included with Ubuntu.

Comment: @gyropyge are you sure about that?

Comment: If you don't have an answer, why are you wasting our time with a post??

Comment: @John, probably because he's contemplating whether it's on topic enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Excel migration page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/UserGuide/Migration_Guide/Calc_and_Excel):

> **Working across spreadsheets, web pages and database data**
>
> *Links created using the prevous examples, including the Navigator’s drag and drop method, do not update automatically.*
>
> To update them, use Edit > Links > [select the desired link] > Update.
> The update works from the saved file – so if both files are open and
> the file that the link is based on is updated, that file must be saved
> before updating the link.
>
> To have persistent updating of data between two spreadsheets, insert
> Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) links:
>
> - Select and copy the range of cells to be linked to.
> - Change to the spreadsheet that requires the link and select the place where you want the link to be. (text on the wiki is not complete; [reference](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=74362&p=336345#p336345) for the edit)
> - Open the Paste Special dialog, Edit > Paste Special and check the Link option (the checkbox at the bottom left of the dialog).
> - Click OK to insert the DDE link.
>
> These cells will have a persistent link to the contents of the other
> sheet and the values returned can then be used in other formulas.

---

[From ask.libreoffice](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/38904/automatic-update-of-references-between-calc-documents/):

A live update of external references isn't implemented. Also in Excel that works only as long as you have both the linking and the linked document open at the same time.

Comment: I was most surprised to find that incomplete sentence in the quoted section beside the second bullet, so I opened the link.  How unfortunate that even the official page has incomplete information.

Comment: The correct way to respond is to update the question if you know what it needs to be. For now I sent a mail to the creator of the page; I am sure it'll get updated.

Comment: Copy and Past Special works, as does edit/link/update. Thanks for your help! Turns out that the link was duplicating because I saved the spreadsheets as .xls -- saving as .ods makes it work fine.

Comment: @John oh that's a good one :D Doesn't state it needs to be .ods :D Don't forget to accept the answer if it is worth accepting ;)